# Slow sync since Constantinople reason?

Tags: parity, synchronization

Noticed two days ago my live ETH node has not been able to keep up with the network.  It is a fast VPS that always was fine until two days ago.

Running 2.3.5-stable of Parity.

Block generation is always a little faster than I can sync.  This never happened before.

Am I the only one experiencing this?

Comment: Details about the VM would be helpful, like vcores / ram / is it hdd or ssd or nvme storage, parity configuration too ( is it a full node? archival node? light ? ) and so on.

Comment: @MickySocaci I understand in theory why you say that but the important factor here is that it was running well until the fork.  So that is the change.  Anyway SSD, 16GB RAM.  I don't know how many cores.  It's a fast VM that is used for production.